# Facebook Javascript SDK localhost error message

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to log into facebook here is my code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>    
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=221385331301885";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script> 
    <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="300"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '221385323101885', // App ID
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Additional initialization code here
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));
    </script>
</form>
</body>
```

When I run this code i get this error message:

[image]

I tried debugging the URL in the window using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug however it kept on telling me URL is not scrapable :/ The URL is below if you want to try debug it:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=221385331301885&app_id=221385331301885&client_id=221385331301885&display=popup&domain=127.0.0.1&locale=en_GB&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%23cb%3Df4b3e7f08%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F127.0.0.1%253A81%252Ff22a06766%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dpostmessage%26frame%3Df23609e538&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&sdk=joey
```

I changed my hosts file to add an entry for 127.0.0.1 localhost.local to match my Facbook App Settings. Below are screenshots of my hosts file and my facebook app settings:

[image: Hosts File]

[image: Facbook App Settings]

As you can see the domain is the same in both the hosts file and the facebook app settings. Any ideas on how i can solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found your problem, but I'm not sure why it happens...

I tried to do exactly what you did, but instead with a *Mobile Web* I had *http://localhost* in the *Website* option (and the mobile was empty). And everything worked fine.

When I switched it from *Website* to *Mobile Web* I got the same error you reported.
Do you **have** to use the mobile option?

Also, you are loading the fb sdk twice, not sure why, first time with this source:

> //connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=221385331301885

And then again with this source:

> "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"

What's the point? What's wrong with simply doing this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="300"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
        appId: '221385323101885', // App ID
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
</script>
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I have issue, i have added http://localhost.local as web site url but still i am getting `GET http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=28 403 (Forbidden) `

Comment: i have created virtual host "localhost.local" and used above code

Answer (score 3):

Add in `Site URL : http://localhost` works for me

Answer (score 0):

Now you must create a virtual host in Apache